# Qt / Qml: calling JavaScript function every time a state change happend

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, signals, slot

I have defined my own component called "StatusLed.qml"

File **StatusLed.qml**

```
Rectangle
{

    id: root
    width: 20
    height: 20
    color: "#008b30"
    radius: 10
    border.color: "#00000000"

    function changeColor()
    {
        root.color = "yellow"
        root.radius = 0
    }

    MouseArea
    {
        id: clickArea
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    states:
    [
        State {
            name: "GO"
            PropertyChanges { target: root; color: "green" }

        },

        State {
            name: "NOGO"
            PropertyChanges { target: root; color: "red" }
        },

        State {
            name: "SELECTABLE"
            PropertyChanges { target: root; color: "green" }
            PropertyChanges { target: clickArea; onClicked: changeColor() }
        }
    ]
}
```

I used this component in my main UI-File / window

File **main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls 6.2
import "./content"

Window
{
    id: root
    width: 1500
    height: 900

    function controlLeds()
    {
        if(standby_led1.state == "GO")
        {
            standby_led2.state = "SELECTABLE"
            standby_led3.state = "SELECTABLE"
        }
        else
        {
            standby_led2.state = "NOGO"
            standby_led3.state = "NOGO"
        }
    }

    StatusLed {
            id: standby_led1
            state: "NOGO"
            onStatesChanged: controlLeds()
        }

        StatusLed {
            id: standby_led2
            state: "NOGO"
            onStatesChanged: controlLeds()
        }

        StatusLed {
            id: standby_led3
            state: "NOGO"
            onStatesChanged: controlLeds()
        }
}
```

So far so good.
What I'm trying to do is:

I want to execute the JavaScript funtion controlLeds() every time if one of the 3 LEDs have changed his state. This function checks the current state of LED1 and would change the state of the other 2 LEDs (LED2 and LED3) depending on it.
I wrongly assumed that a corresponding signal would be triggered so that I could call the function through the onStatesChanged() slot.
Since this is not working now, I would like to know how I can solve this?
How do I trigger the controlLeds() function?

Many thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the two properties `state` and `states`. The property `state` is the name of the current state, whereas the property `states` is the collection of `State` objects as defined in `StatusLED.qml`. You have bound the `controlLeds` function to the latter, which doesn't change since no states are added/deleted (note that the triggering of a `State` does not mean the collection `states` changes)

What you are after is to bind to `onStateChanged`.

However, I see a binding loop coming, so I propose the following solution:

```
StatusLed {
    id: standby_led1
    state: "NOGO" #I assume this is altered from logic not in the question
}
StatusLed {
    id: standby_led2
    state: standby_led1.state == "GO" ? "SELECTABLE" : "NOGO"
}
StatusLed {
    id: standby_led3
    state: standby_led1.state == "GO" ? "SELECTABLE" : "NOGO"
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. This solved my problem. Many thanks for that!